# I want to downgrade my php version to 5.2 (or around)

Tags: php, easyphp, downgrade

In my archives I have an old version of Drupal (Drupal 6.14, 2009-09-16)
I want to be able to reconstitute the website on my local machine (computer)

My problem:
I want to downgrade my php version to 5.2.. (or around) cause my Drupal files does not work with php 5.4...
Now I have installed on my local computer an old version of Easyphp 12.1

```
APACHE  2.4.2 
MYSQL  5.5.27 
PHP  5.4.6
```

How can I downgrade my php version? Do I need to uninstall easyphp?

Answer (score 0):

yes, the easy way is to install again the easy php with the version of php that you want.

Comment: Thanks Bruno Kardis. I have installed an easyphp with a version php5.3.0. Mysql doesn't work but the php is working. I don't really mind about the Mysql. As my db is also on a remote server (not on my computer) I d'like to know how (syntax) I can point on the settings.php of Drupal the location of my db that is on the remote server?

Comment: this questions i dont know how to respond, its better to create a new question: How to connect Drupal (local machine) to a Mysql (remote server)?
and provide the information about your environment: version of: php, drupal, apache, easyphp, mysql
Respond if its dynamic IP or static IP where are your machine, and for the remote server mysql.
And provite some code that you tried.